# How to find the DataBase type of a bound DataGridView column

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview, sqldatatypes

I need to know the original type of each column in my DataGridView.

It is bound with a dynamic SQL select, say, `"SELECT * FROM artists;"`

I want to add a form view of the data above the grid and am programmtically creating Labels and TextBoxes and then some to hold the fields. I add them to a FlowLayoutPanel but I would like to adapt the sizes, especially the multiline property and the height to accomodate long comment and description fields of say 200-500 characters.

All I found when looking into the text columns was datatype `string`.

I know I can look up the columns by querying the systables, but it would be nice to find the original datatype a bit closer than that; also I'm using MYSQL atm, and a solution that doesn't need to query the database would hopefully also be DBMS independent.

**Edit 1**

I fill the DGV with nothing fancy:

```
DBDA = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, DBC);
MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(DBDA);
DBDS = new DataSet(ddlb_tables.Text);
DBDA.FillSchema(DBDS, SchemaType.Mapped);  //<- This was the missing piece of code!!
DBDA.Fill(DBDS, ddlb_tables.Text);
dataGridView1.DataSource = DBDS;
dataGridView1.DataMember = ddlb_tables.Text;
```

**Edit 2**

With the help of the accepted answer (`DBDA.MissingSchemaAction`) I could solve my problem. Here is the resulting function in its first, raw version:

```
public int getColumnSize(DataGridViewColumn dc)
{
  try
  {
    DataGridView DGV = dc.DataGridView;
    DataSet DS = (DataSet)DGV.DataSource;
    DataTable DT = DS.Tables[0];
    DataColumn DC = DT.Columns[dc.Name];
    return DC.MaxLength;
  } catch { }
  return -1;
}
```

Not getting the original type is not a problem, as long as I know the length of the fields.

Comment: how you fill the `DataGridView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the DataSet instead DataGrid:

```
foreach (DataColumn col in DBDS[ddlb_tables.Text].Text.Columns)
{
    if (col.DataType == typeof(string))
    {
        var len = col.MaxLenght;
        ...
    }
}
```

EDIT:

You may need to add the following line before filling:

```
   DBDA.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
```

Source: [The DataAdapter.Fill method does not set all of the properties of the DataTable and DataColumn objects](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310373)

EDIT 2:

Or for result sets without a key:

```
   DBDA.FillSchema(DBDS, SchemaType.Source);
```

Or:

```
   DBDA.FillSchema(DBDS, SchemaType.Mapped);
```

Comment: How would that help me? I need to know the Maximum Length of the column. I have looked deep into the DataTable with the Debugger but all varchar etc datatypes were already mapped to string.

Comment: You check after filling? Are you sure that the database limiting the length of the columns? MSDN: `If the column has no maximum length, the value is -1 (default).`

Comment: Yes and yes. I checked after filling with all 2223 rows on board and in the MYSQL all varchar and char Columns have the CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH set to the respective sizes. (This happens automatically.)

Comment: This works as long as the result set has a key, but for e.g. a keyless `view` it crashes. I took the liberty to add an alternative but safe solution, so that the accepted answer has all the information needed, ok?